# Wordpress questionnaire and open ended answer

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a wordpress plugin that simply lets me ask the user a question and have a text box that lets them enter an answer as they please. I've looked at many questionnaire plugins but they all seem to have just the option to answer the question from a selection of sample answers. i.e checkboxes with answer a, b or c etc.

Comment: What's the purpose of answering this question?  What do you do with the result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any form builder plugin. Not only questionnaire plugins. Unless there is a reason that you cannot and we cannot understand without more content on your question.

- [Ninja forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ninja-forms/)
- [Gravity Forms](https://www.gravityforms.com/)
- [Formidable Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/formidable/)

Are only some of them. Create a new Form. Add a paragraph element for your Question and a textarea for the answer.

Then you can use a shortcode to load it on the page and check the answers on the submitted entries on the backend.

Comment: I would add ACF to this list too.